# Change Wordpress theme programatically for logged in users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-thesis-theme

I need to change the wordpress website theme for logged in users. I figured this code:

```
require_once (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
add_filter( 'template', 'change_theme_template' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'change_theme_template' );
function change_theme_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :\
         $template = 'twentyfifteen';
    endif;

    return $template;
}
```

But it works only for parent themes, it does not work for child theme. I can't find a function to make it work with children. Is there a way to do it? Thank you

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142420/64742 -- just use the stylesheet filter if  it's a child theme.

Comment: It only works if it is a child theme of the original theme (appereance->themes). But I want to show logged in users a child theme of other different theme, it does not work (displays all distorted). Any thought? I have been looking for solution and I am kind of running out of ideas. I hope I make sense.

Comment: I don't have any ideas. If I had to show a different layout, I would load a different stylesheet and use hooks to show different things or I would use the body class .logged-in to prefix what is shown to logged in users (if it's simple enough). Since the way WordPress gets the functions of the parent theme, it wouldn't occur to me to consider your idea since I know it won't work (or would be too painful or time consuming to figure out).

Comment: Thanks anyways for your time :)